Is there a digraph with these 3 properties?
I'm wondering if there exists a digraph on the vertex set $\mathbb{Z}$ satisfying these conditions:

Each vertex has first outdegree equal to second outdegree

(Note: The second outdegree of a vertex $v$ is the number of vertices that can be reached in 2 steps exactly from $v$, not including the vertices reachable in one step.)


Each vertex is reachable from every other vertex by a series of arcs
There is a fixed length which no arc exceeds

I ran into this question while playing with Seymour's Second Neighborhood Conjecture, so I'm only interested in digraphs like the ones in that conjecture. Namely:

No loops
No 2-cycles
No multiple edges

I'm able to find a digraph if I remove conditions 1 or 2, as the below examples show. But I haven't been able to satisfy all 3, and I'm starting to wonder if this is impossible. I would also consider the question answered if this is shown to be equivalent to the Second Neighborhood Conjecture, although the statement is quite different so I don't think that's the case.


The simplest example is the cyclic digraph of V vertices where each indegree and each outdegree is 1 and the maximum distance is V-1.

@R.J.Mathar I need the vertex set to be $\mathbb{Z}$. If I understand right, the one you're talking about is finite?

One start could be to see that all the outdegrees must be the same. For any node $v$, its predecessor $v'$ cannot have a smaller outdegree than $v$ because its second neighborhood contains the successors of $v$. Since there is a backwards path from any node to any other node, there cannot be two nodes with different outdegrees

Okay maybe that is not true because there can be overlap in the neighborhoods of $v'$ and $v$.

Hmm I still don't have an example that satisfies 1 and 2 but not 3. If anyone finds one let me know and I will add it to the question. But with how much trouble I've had finding it, I increasingly think 1 and 2 might be incompatible on their own.

When you say "first out-degree = second out-degree", I assume you are excluding the case where both are infinite? So you want a locally finite digraph?

@BrandonduPreez Yes. Of course, property 3 implies that, so it doesn't need to be said in the question itself. But when I said "I still don't have an example that satisfies 1 and 2 but not 3," I meant a locally finite example.

And really, I just need finite outdegrees. I don't care if there are nodes with infinite indegree.

Note: this answer assumes the wrong definition of the second-out-neighborhood! The right definition is the number of vertices at distance 2, not the number of vertices reachable in exactly two steps.
This is not possible.
Call our graph $G$.
If $a$ and $b$ are in $\mathbb{Z}$ and there is an edge $e$ between them in either direction, I will call $|b-a|$ the distance of the edge $e$.
Let $w$ be the fixed but arbitrary length that no arc exceeds.
I will define a silver node $v$ as a node where all of the nodes in $v$'s out-neighborhood have the same out-degree as $v$.
I will define a golden node $v$ as a node where all of the nodes that are reachable from $v$ are silver nodes.
I will define a loop as a path through the graph from a vertex to itself.
I will also define a generation numbering of all the nodes in a graph with a distinguished root as follows. Let the $0$th generation be the root of the graph. In general, let the generation of a node be the length of the shortest path from the root to that node.
The first-out-degree of a node is the same thing as the out-degree of a node; I will sometimes use it for emphasis.
I use node and vertex interchangeably.
Lemma 101: Each vertex has out-degree at most $2w$.
There are $2w+1$ vertices within a radius of $w$ from a given point $a \in \mathbb{Z}$. However, self-loops are prohibited, leaving $2w$ possibilities.
Lemma 102: No vertex has out-degree $0$.
If a vertex $v$ had out-degree zero, then it would be a dead end and no other vertices would be reachable from it.
Lemma 103: For any given vertex $v$, no member of $v$'s out-neighborhood has strictly higher out-degree than $v$.
Fix an arbitrary vertex $v$.
Suppose $v$ has a vertex in its out-neightborhood $m$ with out-degree strictly higher than $v$. It follows that the second-out-degree of $v$ would thus be strictly higher than the first out degree.
Lemma 104: For a silver node $v$, all nodes in its out-neighborhood have the same out-neighborhood.
$v$ is a silver node. Call its out-neighborhood $O$. This means that every node in the out-neighborhood of $v$ has the same out-degree as $v$. If the out-neighboords of elements of $O$ were distinct, then the second-out-degree of $v$ would be higher than the first, contradicting our hypothesis.
Lemma 105: $G$ contains a golden node.
Suppose that $G$ did not contain any golden nodes.
This means that, starting at an arbitrary vertex $v$, we would eventually be able to reach a vertex $s(v)$ with strictly smaller out-degree. By repeating this process, we would eventually be able to reach a node with out-degree zero, which is impossible by lemma 102.
Lemma 106: Every member of the out-neighborhood of a golden node is golden.
This follows immediately from the definition of a golden node.
Lemma 107: If a graph generated by a golden node $a$ contains a loop of length less than or equal to three involving $a$, then it is finite.
By the rules of the problem, we cannot have a loop of length 1 or 2.
Suppose we have a loop of length three $(a, b, c, a)$.
Let $j$ the out-degree of $a$.
$a$ is in generation $0$, $b$ is in generation $1$ and $c$ is in generation $2$.
Let $N$ be the out-neighborhood of $a$, $O$ be the out-neighborhood of $b$, and $P$ be the out-neighborhood of $c$.

The out-neighborhood of every member of generation $1$ is $O$ by Lemma 104.
The out-neighborhood of every member of generation $2$ is $P$ by Lemma 104.
Note that $P$ contains $a$, whose out-neighborhood is $N$.

This means that we can explore at most $j-1$ options in generation $3$, and that each of those options has $N$ as its out-neighborhood.
However, the next time around on generation $5$, we must make the same choice again as we are visiting already-visited nodes.
Lemma 108: If a graph generated by a golden node $a$ contains any loop going to the root, then it is finite.
Let $k$ be the length of the shortest loop from $a$ to itself.
Let $j$ be the out-degree of $a$.
By a similar argument to the one used in Lemma 107, the out-neighborhood of every member of generation $k-1$ contains $a$.
So we can visit at most $j-1$ new things in generation $k$, but after that we cannot visit anything new.
This is essentially remarking that we did not use the length of the loop in the proof of Lemma 107 in an essential way, only that the elements are distinct. The distinctness of our elements in this proof is given to us by the assumption that the loop in 108 in the shortest possible loop.
Lemma 109: If $G$ does not contain a golden node $a$ with a loop from $a$ to itself.
If $G$ contained a golden node $a$ with a loop, then by Lemma 108 the graph generated by this node would be finite, which would mean that almost all of $\mathbb{Z}$ is unreachable given a starting position of $a$, contradicting our hypothesis.
Theorem: $G$ does not exist.
By Lemma 105, $G$ contains a golden node. Call it $a$.
Let $b$ be a member of the out-neighborhood of $a$.
By hypothesis, there exists some path from $b$ back to $a$.
However, this contradicts Lemma 109, since this would be a golden node with a loop.

Lemma 109's statement seems incomplete.

Thanks for the well-written answer! Unfortunately, I don't think the proof of Lemma 103 works. Say that we have vertices $v$, $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$, with arcs $v \rightarrow a$, $v \rightarrow b$, $a \rightarrow b$, $a \rightarrow c$, and $a \rightarrow d$. Then $a$ is in $v$'s outneighborhood and has higher outdegree than $v$, and yet $v$ has first outdegree equal to second outdegree.

@Archr In your example, isn't $v$'s out-neighborhood ${a, b}$ and its second-out-neighborhood ${ b, c, d }$ since those are the vertices that I can reach in two steps?

Or is $b$ excluded from the second-out-neighborhood because the shortest path to it has length 1?

Yes, $b$ is excluded because the second neighborhood is only the vertices at distance 2. Sorry, I'll update the question to clarify that. A few people have thought the same thing you did.

Using the wrong definition certainly does make the problem easier.
